# File reading difference in Ruby and Mac OS due to different encoding

Tags: ruby, file, encoding

I have a file test.conf on mac . I downloaded it from web location as application/octet.

When I check for the mime type using the commandline I get:

```
 file -Ib ~/test.conf 
 text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

But in Ruby's IRB, I see it as utf-8:

```
 irb(main):039:0> f = File.open("test.conf")
 => #<File:test.conf>
irb(main):040:0> f.external_encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
irb(main):041:0> contents = f.read
irb(main):042:0> contents.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

So when I try to open the file for reading one line at a time using `File.foreach` I get 52 lines, whereas

```
cat ~/test.conf | wc -l
12
```

So my dilemma here is, how do I make sure Ruby sees the same number of lines as the `cat` command?

Comment: Ruby sees **52 symbols**, not **52 lines**.

Comment: File uses a set of rules to determine what a file's content is, but it's hardly exhaustive and can be easily fooled, especially when dealing with a document that has diacriticals deep in the file. You can ask the serving host what it thinks the encoding is, but that can be wrong too. Sometimes the only solution is based on your advance knowledge of what the file's true encoding is. We have no idea what is in your file, so any answers we give you are wild guessing. Perhaps you should reduce the file to the bare minimum that will demonstrate the problem and add it to the question?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own qs: Since my file size is small, I used the following:

```
    content = File.open("test.conf",'r:UTF-8',&:read) 
    content.lines.each do |l|
      < do whatever with l > 
    end
```

Thank You